# Angular 12 datetime picker 1 registers 1 day before the day I select

Tags: angular, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format, angular12

```
  **HTML**
  <mat-form-field class="w-1/2 ml-3">
    <mat-label>Assignment Deadline</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName='deadline' [min]="today" [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**typescript**

```
this.homeworkForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  //,
  deadline: [data.deadline, [Validators.required]],
 //
})
```

to resolve my error datetime should not save 1 day ago
I can't find any solution please help

Comment: Tried read your question multiple times, but still not understand. Can you specify what is your expected result and your current issue? Thanks.

Comment: His problem is that the control returns the value in UTC and save it wrong in DB and when is sending it back to the control is with one day less.

Comment: my problem is i choose a date from datetime picker example: 01/09/2023 but when saving it saves as 31/08/2023

It throws it back 3 hours because it uses utc, so it throws it back one day

Comment: This is likely a problem with the format of the date. Could you give an example for a value of `data.deadline`? Ideally this is an ISO string.

Comment: data.deadline:2023-08-30T21:00:00 

Since this date throws the time back 3 hours instead of 00:00, it records 1 day ago. I saw this problem in many people in angular.

Comment: but when you call GET api for date you get the same date that you expected in angular. right?

Comment: !! I found the solution = data.deadline =  new Date(data.deadline._d.getTime() + 3*60*60*1000)